# AngularJS directive only when the condition is true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am going to have a contextmenu directive in ng-repeat items.
Based on whether a condition is true, the directive should be applied.
How do I put a condition like only when item.hasMenu == true then apply the directive ?

```
<ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
<li contextmenu ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

This seems to have worked for me. First the directive.

```
app.directive('menu',function(){

    return {
        restrict : 'A',

        link : function(scope,element,attrs){

            if(scope.hasMenu){
                        element.contextmenu({
                                        menu:[
                                        {title:"Remove" , "cmd" : "remove"},
                                        {title:"Add" , "cmd" : "add"},
                                        ],
                                        select:function(event,ui){
                                            //alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on" + ui.target.text());
                                            if (ui.cmd ==='remove'){
                                                alert('Remove selected on ' + scope.item);
                                            }
                                            if (ui.cmd ==='add'){
                                                alert("Add selected");
                                            }
                                        }
                        });
            }

        }
    }
    }
);
```

Then the html

```
 <ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
<li menu  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show the contextmenu directive template?  Where are you adding the markup for the context menu?

Comment: I am trying to use https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu as the directive. So far I haven't created the directive. This particular plugin has delegate function to filter elements based on the class. I am thinking to use that as the filter criteria but not sure if that'll work.

Comment: In that case you should be able to use `ng-class="{'hasmenu': item.hasMenu}`.

Answer (score 6):

Can you do something like this, using `ng-if`?

```
<ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <div contextmenu ng-if="item.hasMenu"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

[Here are the docs for ng-if.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf)

EDIT:
If you are driving the context menu off of a class, you should be able to do this:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
   <li ng-class="{'hasmenu': item.hasMenu}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty tricky if you don't want to change your DOM structure. If you could just place your `contextmenu` directive on a sub DOM node inside the `<li>` things would be a lot easier.

However, let's assume you can't do that and let's also assume that you don't own the `contextmenu` directive so that you can't change it to your needs.

Here is a possible solution to your problem that might be a bit hackish (actually I don't know!)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name:1, hasMenu: true}, 
        {name:2, hasMenu: false }, 
        {name:3, hasMenu: true}
      ];
  }])
  .directive('contextmenu', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element){
        element.css('color', 'red');
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('applyMenu', ['$compile', function($compile){

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element){
        if (scope.item.hasMenu){
          //add the contextmenu directive to the element
          element.attr('contextmenu', '');
          //we need to remove this attr
          //otherwise we would get into an infinite loop
          element.removeAttr('apply-menu');

          //we also need to remove the ng-repeat to not let the ng-repeat 
          //directive come between us.
          //However as we don't know the side effects of 
          //completely removing it, we add it back after
          //the compile process is done.
          var ngRepeat = element.attr('ng-repeat');
          element.removeAttr('ng-repeat');
          var enhanced = $compile(element[0])(scope);
          element.html(enhanced);
          element.attr('ng-repeat', ngRepeat);
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

I faked the `contextmenu` directive to just change the `color` to `red` just so that we can see it's taking place.

Then I created an `apply-menu` attribute directive. This directive than checks if the `hasMenu` property is true and if so hooks in and adds the `contextmenu` directive and does a manual `$compile` process.

However, what worries me a bit about this solution is that I had to temporally remove the `ng-repeat` directive (and also the `apply-menu` directive) to get the `$compile` process to act the way we want it to act. We then add the `ng-repeat` directive back once the `$compile` has been made. That is because we don't know the side effects of removing it entirely from the resulting html. This might be perfectly valid to do, but it feels a bit arkward to me.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KrygjX

Comment: Hi @Christoph. I added the if condition in your applyMenu directive directly into the contextmenu directive. I didn't see any side effects.Yes it is awkward to remove `ng-repeat`

Comment: So you changed the code in a directive which you don't own? That leads to a maintenance nightmare!

Comment: No I didn't change the code of directive. I just added a condition that will determine if the element will have a `contextmenu` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
angularApp.directive('element', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',  
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            require: '?ngModel',
            scope: 'isolate',
            link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                $scope.isTrue = function() {
                    return attr.hasMenu;
                };
              if($scope.isTrue())
                //some html for control
                elem.html('').show();
              else
                //some html for control
                elem.html('').show(); 

                $compile(elem.contents())($scope);

            }
        };
    });
```